# update/refresh the frame of UIScrollView after it's creation once

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, refresh, frame

```
self.scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.bounds),CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds),CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds),CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.hourView];

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.gridView];
```

Now after embedding some views in the gridview, I get some `coordinates(x,y,width,height)`. Now I want to refresh the frame of my scrollview with these `coordinates(x,y,width,height)`.

Since the scrollview is already created once,so What should I do to update or refresh it's frame?

Comment: Nothing just again set the frame of scrollview when you will get the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update it by same way as you have doen initially.

```
scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: but it does not get updated or refreshed, since I want the scrollview to contain an area(of the grid and hour view) different from the previous one that it contained.

Comment: This line should work. I think you are doing mistake in setting frame. Please keep in mind frame works relative to parent view(i.e. according to coordinate of parent view)

Comment: tell me one more thing; if I have used setcontentsize with the frame creation initially, then do I need to make changes to that too,to get the correct results..??

Comment: Frame is the visible area of your scroll view. Suppose you are setting 10pixle of frame then user can see your scrollview in width of 10 pixel. And contentsize is the actual size of your scrollview. let take the example of book reader at a time you can see the one page(i.e. depends on frame) but content size of your scrollview is the "content-size-width=number of pages*width of scrollview". Here width of scrollview means frame width of scrollview. So,if you are changing the width of content then you must set content size to make scrollview content display proper.

Answer (score 0):

U can call `[yourScrollView setFrame:CGRectmake(,,,)];` any time you need